# multiple insertRules to one CSS style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently writing a simple jQuery plugin where I need to insert around 30 to 40 rules into a single stylesheet tag, right now the current code I'm using was written by another StackOverflow user. It does the job, but it creates a separate style tag for each rule, how should I modify this code to get it all in one tag? (I'm still working on Javascript, so I don't fully understand the source.)

```
(
function( $ )
{
    $.style={
        insertRule:function(selector,rules,contxt)
        {
            var context=contxt||document,stylesheet;



            if(typeof context.styleSheets=='object')
            {
                if(context.styleSheets.length)
                {
                    stylesheet=context.styleSheets[context.styleSheets.length-1];
                }
                if(context.styleSheets.length)
                {
                    if(context.createStyleSheet)
                    {
                        stylesheet=context.createStyleSheet();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(context.createElement('style'));
                        stylesheet=context.styleSheets[context.styleSheets.length-2];
                    }
                }
                if(stylesheet.addRule)
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<selector.length;++i)
                    {
                        stylesheet.addRule(selector[i],rules);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    stylesheet.insertRule(selector.join(',') + '{' + rules + '}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);  
                }
            }
            console.log(selector + " { " + rules + " }");
        }
    }; 
}
)( jQuery );
```

Comment: How are you recognizing the stylesheet to which you want to add rules? Or should only one new stylesheet be created?

Comment: Only one stylesheet. I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these (patterns)

```
   $(function() {
      var styles = "body{background:blue}"
      +"div{color:#fff;}";
      $("<style>", {
          "id" : "styles",
          "text" : styles
      })
      .appendTo("head");
      var rules = ["span{color:red;font-size:24px;}", "em{background:gold;}"];
      $.each(rules, function(index, value){
        $("#styles").append("\n" + value);;
      });
   })
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/4MQyY/

Comment: I decided to keep the same arguments and ways to call the insertRule function, but I used your technique and it's certainly the best and most pain free. Here's my new code: `(function($){ $.style={ insertRule:function(selector,rules,contxt){ console.log(selector+" { "+rules+" } "); $("#griddy-styles").append("\n"+selector+" { "+rules+" } ");}}; })( jQuery );`